# OpenCl : Speed comparison of using global memory and private memory

Tags: opencl

I am learning OpenCl and I've stumble upon these two code snippets and now I am wondering why using private memory is much faster than just using global memory.

```
kernel void mmul(
   const int N,
   global float* A,
   global float* B,
   global float* C)
 {
     int k, j;
     int i = get_global_id(0);
     float tmp;
     if (i < N) {
         for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
             tmp = 0.0f;
             for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                 tmp += A[i*N+k] * B[k*N+j];
             C[i*N+j] = tmp;
         }
     }
 }
```

and between this

```
kernel void mmul(
   const int N,
   global float* A,
   global float* B,
   global float* C)
 {
     int k, j;
     int i = get_global_id(0);
     float Awrk[2048];
     float tmp;
     if (i < N) {
         for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
             Awrk[k] = A[i*N+k];

         for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
             tmp = 0.0;
             for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                 tmp += Awrk[k] * B[k*N+j];
             C[i*N+j] = tmp;
         }
     }
 }
```

On the bottom code snippet, the code assigns a memory, Awrk[2048], and copies data from the global float A, which I think it is waste of operation. However, the bottom code is much faster (4.27 seconds) than the top one (about 14 seconds). Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: On both cases "A" is accessed N*N times. But on the second case only N memory accesses are performed to global memory that is a big reduction.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Thank you!